# Wait for AngularJS Service to finish running (chrome console)

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I'm manipulating some angular services/functions via Chrome console.  *(I have to specifically do this for a task I'm working on).*

What I want to do is wait for the `AddBagIfLimitNotReached()` function to execute and finish running.  And only then access the variable `this.option.Quantity`.

```
angular.element(document.querySelector(".quantity-button")).controller()._registeredControls[1].Scope.AddBagIfLimitNotReached = async function(n) {
    console.log("tthis", this)
        if (this.HasReachedMaximumBaggageAllowance()) {
            angular.element(document.querySelector(".quantity-button")).controller()._registeredControls[1].LuggageDrawersService.OpenLuggageLimitReachedDrawer();
            return;
        }
        this.AddBag(n);
        console.log("Quantity", this.option.Quantity);
};
```

With this function, I'm adding a product to my basket.  And `this.option.Quantity` should console.log `1`.  But it actually consoles.log `0`.

However, if I check the object itself, it shows `1`.

So I think what is happening, is I'm console.logging my bag quantity, before the bag has actually finished being added to the basket.

For example, if I added a `settimeout` of 2 seconds, the correct bag value = 1 is console.logged.

```
angular.element(document.querySelector(".quantity-button")).controller()._registeredControls[1].Scope.AddBagIfLimitNotReached = async function(n) {
    console.log("tthis", this)
        if (this.HasReachedMaximumBaggageAllowance()) {
            angular.element(document.querySelector(".quantity-button")).controller()._registeredControls[1].LuggageDrawersService.OpenLuggageLimitReachedDrawer();
            return;
        }
        this.AddBag(n);

        // Returns 1
        setTimeout(function(){ console.log("Quantity", this.option.Quantity); }, 2000);
};
```

Is there a better way I can achieve this, without using settimeout?  I have tried async/await/promises, but I still can't seem to find a way to wait for the function to finish loading.

Async/await returns an error - it doesn't like the function `this.HasReachedMaximumBaggageAllowance()` and throws an error stating `this.HasReachedMaximumBaggageAllowance is not a function`.

Any tips/ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to show us `HasReachedMaximumBaggageAllowance` and `AddBag` function. Otherwise, hard to tell if you are doing the right thing.

Comment: Also, what is `this` is binded to? `Scope`?

Comment: Yeah this is binded to Scope, which is basically an object, which contains data about the bag being added.  For example. this.option.quanity = 1.  this.bag.weight = 50kg. etc etc

- HasReachedMaximumBaggageAllowance() checks to see that the bag limit is.  And addBag, POSTs the bag object to the server.

The thing is, the code is waaaay too much to share.  It's literally hundreds on lines, for just these two functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I'm using `$watch`, to watch a key/value, in the `this` object.  And this seems to work:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector(".quantity-button.plus-button")).controller()._registeredControls[1].Scope.AddBagIfLimitNotReached = function(n) {
    let bagCount = this.option.Quantity;
    console.log("bagCount", bagCount);

        if (this.HasReachedMaximumBaggageAllowance()) {
            angular.element(document.querySelector(".quantity-button.plus-button")).controller()._registeredControls[1].LuggageDrawersService.OpenLuggageLimitReachedDrawer();
            return;
        };

        this.AddBag(n);
        this.$watch("this.option.Quantity", function (newValue) {
            console.log(`Value of foo changed ${newValue}`);
            if (newValue > 0) {
                document.querySelector(`.luggage-tile-weight-${n.Weight} .tile-title .tick-box`).classList.add("green-tick");
                displayGreenTickNoBagSelected();
            };
            if (newValue === 0) {
                document.querySelector(`.luggage-tile-weight-${n.Weight} .tile-title .tick-box`).classList.remove("green-tick");
                displayGreenTickNoBagSelected();
            };
        });
};
```